# Heroku rake task with poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, capybara, poltergeist

I'm writing a rake task which tests an application. To test it I need Capybara and Poltergeist.
Rake task looks like this:

```
require "capybara"
require "capybara/poltergeist"
require "capybara/dsl"

namespace :almet do
  desc "Checking if something changed on tatar.ru"
  task check_news: :environment do
    Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
    Browser = Class.new { include Capybara::DSL }
    page = Browser.new.page
    page.visit("http://almetyevsk.tatar.ru")
    unless page.has_selector?(".home-events ul li") &
       page.has_selector?(".home-events__item-lead") &
       page.has_selector?(".home-events__item-date") &
       page.has_selector?("h2 a")
    then
       alert
    end
    news_link = page.find(:css, "h2 a", match: :first)[:href]
    page.visit(news_link)
    unless page.has_selector?(".page__content-i h2") &
       page.has_selector?(".page__content-i .news") &
       page.has_selector?("i")
    then
       alert
    end
  end

  def alert
    AlertMailer.alert.deliver_now
  end
end
```

This code checks if the main site from parsing data is still the same (no changes in css selectors). This rake task works good locally, but when I pushed it to heroku I've got an error:

```
rake aborted!
Cliver::Dependency::NotFound: Could not find an executable ["phantomjs"] on your path.
```

I googled this, installed phantomJS but still got the same error.(Poltergeist using phantomJS). Is it possible to solve my problem?

Comment: Did you add Phantomjs to your project or in Heroku as a `buildpack`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PhantomJS onto your Heroku instance.  Usually that involves adding a build pack which will install it for you, like https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs